# botocore.exceptions.WaiterError: Waiter InstanceRunning failed: Invalid id: "instance_id"

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I am trying to run an instance which already exists on amazon ec2 via boto3.

```
import sys
import boto3


instance_id = "i-03e7f6391a0f523ee"
action = 'ON'

ec2 = boto3.client('ec2')

if action == 'ON':
   response = ec2.start_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
else:
    response = ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DryRun=False)
print(response)


#resp2=ec2.describe_instances()
#foo = response['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['NetworkInterfaces'][0]['Association']['PublicDnsName']
#filter=[{'Name':'Association','Values':['PublicDnsName']}]

#print (foo)
#instance = ec2.resource('ec2').instance(instance_id)
#while instance.state['Name'] not in ('running', 'stopped'):
#        sleep(5)
#        print("the instance is initializing")
x2=boto3.resource('ec2')
instance=x2.Instance('instance_id')
foo=instance.wait_until_running('self',Filters=[{'Name':'instance-state-name','Values':['running']}])
print ("instance.wait_until_running('self',Filters=[{'Name':'instance-state-name','Values':['running']}]) = "+foo)
```

but in this line

```
foo=instance.wait_until_running('self',Filters=[{'Name':'instance-state-name','Values':['running']}])
```

I get error

```
File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\factory.py", line 369, in do_waiter
    waiter(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\boto3\resources\action.py", line 202, in __call__
    response = waiter.wait(**params)
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\botocore\waiter.py", line 53, in wait
    Waiter.wait(self, **kwargs)
  File "E:\installation2\python3\lib\site-packages\botocore\waiter.py", line 313, in wait
    last_response=response
botocore.exceptions.WaiterError: Waiter InstanceRunning failed: Invalid id: "instance_id"
```

What is wrong here with usage of

```
foo=instance.wait_until_running('self',Filters=[{'Name':'instance-state-name','Values':['running']}])
```

I am just trying to understand how attributes available as mentioned here
https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#instance
can be used in programs. Methods like `wait_until_running` which I am not able to use.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I fixed the problem the problem was caused due to usage of

```
instance=x2.Instance('instance_id')
```

It should rather have been used like this

```
instance=x2.Instance(instance_id)
```